# Optimal trajectory of area exploration

Tags: 2d, algorithm, path-finding

I've got next problem. There is three objects:

1. first one, with next characteristics: circular area of view, speed, drag coefficient;
2. wind (or water current, doesn't matter; some sort of resistance) with some strength and direction;
3. polygon, concave (in general case).

I need to build path of first object inside this polygon, which will:

1. cover whole polygon by view area;
2. be optimal by travel time;
3. takes into account wind direction and strength.

In other words, I need to carry out exploration in a given area on optimal trajectory while scout can be drift away.

Comment: This problem sounds equivalent to those solved by 3D printing algorithms, to decide the best path for the print head to completely cover a given cross-section with the least redundant movement. Your wind parameter is effectively an anisotropy in the drive motor, where it can move faster in one direction than in reverse. Have you looked at such printing algorithms for inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

With **r** being the circular area view radius;

1. Make a mesh that covers the polygon where the nodes are at most 2**r** apart and connect the nodes with neighbours.
2. Based on the distance and wind/water current between each node, add a difficulty value to progress through the arcs; arcs are bi-directional and don't have the same value (for instance for node A to B -> cost is 10, but for B to A -> cost is 20 because of the wind), you'll get a directed graph.
3. Apply a greedy algorithm to [explore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal#Graph_Exploration) all the nodes in the graph.

From the description of your issue, the speed and drag coefficient of 1. are irrelevant as they'll be the same throughout the whole path-finding process.

**Note**:
You **will not** find the *optimal* trajectory with this. You will find a *good* or *okay* trajectory, but unless you want to throw in optimization and meta-heuristics, that's all you're going to get.

---

Optionally, you could try and 'merge' the arcs going from the start of a current to it's end, removing the nodes along the way. This will leave you the optimal path *for this spot*.

Comment: Note that you want the nodes a little closer than 2r apart, otherwise it's possible to make a path that visits every node but still leaves small gaps in the corners between the nodes (because the exploration footprint is circular). It's also worth pointing out that the Hamiltonian Path problem is solvable as a special case of this graph-exploration, so this problem is NP-Complete. Unless we're willing to sink exponential time into the solution, an approximate answer is likely the best we can reasonably expect.

Comment: +1 for the nuance about the distance between nodes. As for the path exploration, I was not suggesting to visit the each node _exactly once_; not sure if adding that constraint would be a good or a bad thing in this precise situation.

Comment: You're right. What I mean is that if we had an algorithm which could always find the shortest path visiting every node in a graph [an abitrary number of times], this could be used in some cases to test for a Hamiltonian path (specifically, in cases where re-visiting a node lengthens the path. If our shortest path revisits a node, then we can conclude that no non-revisiting path was available, answering the Hamiltonian Path problem). I bring this up in support of your choice of greedy algorithms & heuristics, rather than looking for a provably optimal solution, which is likely to be impractical

Comment: @DMGregory whether a problem is NP-complete is meaningless without knowing n. It's often easier since you know that the optimal solution requires exhaustive search, so you don't need to bother with clever algorithms. For example, solving sudoku or looking for moves in match-3 games is often practical with brute force because the board size is so limited. In this case we don't know because OP hasn't specified.

Comment: @congusbongus which is exactly why my statement was preceded by "unless we're willing to sink exponential time into the solution" since that can be a reasonable choice where n is small.  That said, exhaustively searching every permutation of a set of destination points gets impractical after only a couple dozen, so the "small n" case won't get us very far.